# useInfiniteScroll not triggering onLoadMore

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I´m using the dependency react-infinite-scroll-hook in the functional component below, where I do retrieve data from [PokéAPI](https://pokeapi.co/). However, the data is only loaded the first time the function `loadData` is called in `useEffect`, but scrolling to the component with `sentryRef` does not trigger `onLoadMore` in `useInfiniteScroll`. What I'm missing here?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Grid, CircularProgress, capitalize, List, ListItem, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from '@material-ui/core';
import useInfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroll-hook';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Lens } from '@material-ui/icons';

function NationalPokedex(props) {
    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [hasNext, setHasNext] = useState(true);
    const [next, setNext] = useState('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/');

    const loadData = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        console.log("FETCH")
        axios.get(next).then(response => {
            setPokemons([...pokemons, ...response.data.results]);
            if(response.data.next) {
                setNext(response.data.next);
            } else {
                setHasNext(false);
                setNext(null);
            }
            setLoading(false);
        });  
    }

    const [sentryRef] = useInfiniteScroll({
        loading,
        hasNext,
        onLoadMore: loadData,
        disabled: !!hasNext,
        rootMargin: '0px 0px 100px 0px',
    });

    useEffect(loadData, []);

    const renderData = () => {
        var result = [];
        pokemons.map((pokemon) => {
            result.push(<ListItem key={pokemon.name}><ListItemIcon><Lens></Lens></ListItemIcon><ListItemText>{capitalize(pokemon.name)}</ListItemText></ListItem>);
        });
        console.log("LOAD_DATA");
        console.log(hasNext, next, loading, pokemons);
        return result;
    }

    return (
        <>
        <List spacing={3}>
            {renderData()}
        </List>
        {(hasNext || loading) && (
            <Grid container item xs={12} ref={sentryRef} justifyContent='center' key='progress'>
                <CircularProgress/>
            </Grid>
        )}
        </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using another dependency, `react-infinite-scroller`, that works perfectly, so I guess the issue was not on my side.

The code looks like this, in case it is useful for someone:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Grid, CircularProgress, capitalize, List, ListItem, ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from '@material-ui/core';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
import axios from 'axios';
import { Lens } from '@material-ui/icons';

function NationalPokedex(props) {
    const [pokemons, setPokemons] = useState([]);
    const [hasNext, setHasNext] = useState(true);
    const [next, setNext] = useState('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/');

    const loadData = () => {
        axios.get(next).then(response => {
            setPokemons([...pokemons, ...response.data.results]);
            if(response.data.next) {
                setNext(response.data.next);
            } else {
                setHasNext(false);
                setNext(null);
            }
        });  
    }

    const renderData = () => {
        var result = [];
        pokemons.map((pokemon) => {
            result.push(<ListItem key={pokemon.name}><ListItemIcon><Lens></Lens></ListItemIcon><ListItemText>{capitalize(pokemon.name)}</ListItemText></ListItem>);
        });
        return result;
    }

    return (
        <InfiniteScroll
            pageStart={0}
            loadMore={loadData}
            hasMore={hasNext}
            loader={<Grid container item xs={12} justifyContent='center' key='progress'><CircularProgress/></Grid>}
            threshold={0}
        >
            <List>{renderData()}</List>           
        </InfiniteScroll>
    );
}

export default NationalPokedex;
```